# virtualbox + perl + shared folder == fail

Tags: linux, windows, perl, virtualbox, shared-directory

This is a convoluted one so bear with me. I have a Perl script that is located on a Windows VirtualBox guest. I want to call this script from the Linux host and have it read a shared folder from the host. The reading of the folder fails.

On the host I call this script and it gives me the following output:

```
host:~/$ ./script.pl /nfs/nasi/temp
[2014-04-02 10:50:55] Uploading file records to localhost
[2014-04-02 10:50:55] Running VirtualBox for Kaspersky
fatal: opendir(E:\nasi\temp) failed: No such file or directory
[2014-04-02 10:50:56] Uploading malware samples data to localhost
host:$
```

The script converts the argument `/nfs/nasi/temp` to `E:\nasi\temp` and calls the script using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/VBoxManage guestcontrol <guest> execute \
  --image "C:\strawberry\perl\bin    \perl.exe"   \
  --username <user> --password <pass>              \
  --wait-stdout --wait-stderr --wait-exit --        \
  "C:\antivirus\kaspersky.pl" "E:\nasi\temp"
```

When I run this same script using the same option from the guest directly however I get the following:

```
C:\antivirus>C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe C:\antivirus\kaspersky.pl E:\nasi\temp
[2014-04-02 10:54:19] Running Kaspersky Antivirus
[2014-04-02 10:54:20] Parsing Kaspersky report
[2014-04-02 10:54:20] Uploading Kaspersky results to 10.0.0.1
C:\antivirus>
```

But wait, it gets weirder. When instead of providing the shared directory `E:\` I instead point it to `C:\` it has no problem reading the directory and just happily keeps going. So the error only shows up when I run the command from the host through VirtualBox and point it to the share.

Here is the relevant code:

```
sub createSamplesMap {
    opendir( my $dh, $ARGV[0] ) or
        die "fatal: opendir($ARGV[0]) failed: $!\n";
    my @files = readdir( $dh );
    foreach my $file ( @files ) {
        if (! -d $file ) {
            ...
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
```

I tried different ways of reading the filenames from the directory but they didn't work. Here's what I tried.

```
my @files = <$ARGV[0]\\*>;
my @files = glob( $ARGV[0] . '\\*' );
```

I don't know whether to blame perl or virtualbox. Anyone have any ideas on what the problem might be?

- Windows 7, Strawberry Perl v5.18.2
- Ubuntu 12.04.04, Perl v5.14.2
- VirtualBox 4.2.16r86992

crosspost: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=61011

Comment: VirtualBox's shared folders *do* fail me from time to time; sometimes, I just copy files from the shared folder to c:\temp and act on them there.

Comment: Unfortunately the host doesn't really have enough diskspace to store all the files twice, and copying would slow the thing down significantly. Also, right now it fails always so there must be something else going wrong than just unreliable software.

Comment: Simplify the script and just try opening the directory, providing the path as a hardcoded string. That will show whether it is the pathname being odd or the actual path not being available.

Comment: @Richard Huxton, the script works fine and as expected when run directly from the guest with E:\nasi\test. And it works fine with C:\. It also works fine called from the host with C:\. It is only when called from the host with E:\nasi\test that it fails. Also other software fails as well to read the directory, cmd.exe /c dir cannot read the directory either.

Comment: OK, so it's definitely the folder not being readable. That sounds like it's VirtualBox being clever and trapping certain system calls but not  others. You may be able to work around it through one of the Win32 libraries but first step will be to find out from the virtualbox people exactly what it is doing.

Comment: you can make another disk and share it between the different virtual machines; that way, instead of E:\, you would use D:\...

Comment: Do you mean to have space between the `C:\strawberry\perl\bin` and `\perl.exe` ?

Comment: There is two other details I noticed: First, your drive E: seems to be doubly-network-mapped (once by virtualbox and another one via NFS, since its path starts with /nfs ...). Have you tried map it directly via NFS *inside* the Windows VB machine? And second, are you opening a session and logging on with your user beforehand? Because, if not, you may not have the E: drive mapped when your guestcontrol script is executed! try seeing the output of "net use" inside your "kapersky.pl" script...

Comment: @mob no the space is only in the post, I was wrestling with stackoverflow, it kept demanding spaces for code blocks

Comment: @massa I don't understand your first comment about different virtual machines, I only want communication between 1 VM and its host. And I don't think running the shared folder on a different volume is going to change anything.

Comment: @massa you're very observant for noticing the NFS thing. Yes from the guests point of view its just a shared folder to a local directory on the host. But from the hosts perspective this is an NFS mount. Its necessary because the host doesn't have the diskspace to store all the files. I've been looking into connecting the windows guest to the NFS directly, which isn't all that easy. I left that part out of the question because it only solves MY problem of accessing the files not THE problem of getting virtualbox to work.

Comment: @massa I've tried every combination of calling the script that I can think of; I've been logged in as the same user, a different user, not logged in at all, everything. None of that worked. Also, the VirtualBox shared folder isn't a true CIFS network share. So it's visible when you add it through the explorer 'map network drive' functionality and once running all the programs can access the E drive but commands like 'net view' and 'net use' see nothing.

Comment: have you tried opening the file inside kapersky.pl via UNC name? like \\vboxsrv\sharedfoldername ?? my about different virtual machines is because you said that "the machine does not have the diskspace to store the files twice", but now I know what you mean...

As you said, the shared folder is not a true CIFS network share, and that's why your script is not seeing it. My suggestion of trying to connect the windows VM directly to the NFS share is the best suggestion I have for now... :(

Comment: @massa Yeah I had all but given up trying to get the shared folder to work until I ran into the blog post I mentioned in the answer below. Getting NFS to work well in windows is not that easy especially since I don't have access to the NFS server (and configuration options, and having windows professional, and registry settings, and firewall settings, and NAT, phfff). Thankfully it now works as orginally imagined and desired :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem. As mentioned on the virtualbox forum there was a problem with the environment variables set when running the perl script. After much googling I also found a blog post from [kissmyarch](http://kissmyarch.blogspot.nl/2012/01/opening-files-under-virtualbox-guest.html) where he describes how he solved the problem.

You can set environment variables using the --environment option in VBoxManage guestcontrol and according to kissmyarch you need to set USERPROFILE to get it to work. This did not work for me.

So instead I used the following code from the script to figure out what environment variables were set:

```
foreach $key (sort keys(%ENV)) {
  print "$key = $ENV{$key}\n";
}
```

and ran that both on the guest and from guestcontrol to compare the environments. My command now looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/VBoxManage guestcontrol <vm> execute \
   --image "C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" \
   --username <user> --password <pass> \
   --environment "USERPROFILE=C:\Users\<user>" \
   --environment "APPDATA=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming" \
   --environment "LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local" \
   --environment "HOMEDRIVE=C:" \
   --environment "HOMEPATH=\Users\<user>" \
   --environment "LOGONSERVER=\\\<server>" \
   --environment "SESSIONNAME=Console" \
   --environment "TEMP=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp" \
   --environment "TMP=C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp" \
   --environment "USERDOMAIN=<domain>" \
   --environment "USERNAME=<user>" \
   --wait-stdout --wait-stderr --wait-exit \
   -- "C:\antivirus\kaspersky.pl" "E:\nasi\temp"
```

Somewhere in that big pile of environment variables is one that is important.

Thanks to all that helped.